# How to not commit code pieces to git/github

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github

I have some specific code locations in some PHP files that I want to remove before I commit my changes to github, but this code should not be removed from my local repository. It also can't be moved to other files. Is there a way that I can mark these code parts like with some kind of filter to remove them before I commit the changed code?

Comment: This approach does not work with git. If you want to hide data never commit the data. You can ignore files in git so that ey are not commited or use a deployment/builder script that copies the files into a new structure outside of the git repo and injects the relevant information (e.g. using a preprocessor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a script that reads the code file and writes a new file, without the code that you don't want to be committed, and commit that file instead. You can also watch for changes on the original file such that the new file recompiles onChange.

However, for what use case do you not want to commit some specific pieces of code?

Answer (score 0):

I have to re-think how i can come to a solution. For the time beeing, i try to use a include file like the following:

```
$aconfig= "additional_config.php";
if(file_exists($aconfig)) {
    include($aconfig);
}
```

Additionally i add additional_config.php to the .gitignore file. In that file, i have some special config variables for my own environment, which i dont want to include in  GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the files are like private/explicit in some way where you never want them uploaded at all, I would suggest creating a new branch (I like to checkout and create in one command) `git checkout -b new_branch_name` and push that branch to github. That way the original files are kept intact in the original branch. Then once you're done making all your changes and have only material you want committed to the original branch, you can merge the new branch into the original. This would be a normal workflow.